# Probability of getting value 3 on a dice X number of times before getting value 1

Tags: probability

I would like to know how I can calculate the probability of getting the value 3 when rolling a dice at least X number of times before getting the value 1 for example. It is important to note that the X number of times to show 3 does not have to be consecutive. What I want to calculate is getting 3 X times before getting 1. The value 1 here is my stop condition.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you mean at least $X$ times or exactly $X$ times?

Comment: At least X times.

Comment: I modified the original question to be at least X times.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n\geq X$ be an integer. The probability of getting the value 3 $X$ times from the set $\{2,3,4,5,6\}$ is $_{n}C_{X}\left( \frac{1}{5} \right)^{X}\left( \frac{4}{5} \right)^{n-X}$. The probability of getting the value 1 at the $(n+1)$th roll is $\frac{1}{6}$. Therefore the desired probability is:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=X}^{\infty} \left(_{n}C_{X} \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{X}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{n-X} \right)=\frac{5}{6}
\end{align*}

Comment: Does this apply for at least X times?